# What is a single word for people personally close to a King?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word for the people who are part of the inner circle of a king?

It is in the following context from the Quran: Moses was sent to Pharaoh and threw down his staff which became a snake - as a sign that Moses was sent by God.

So Pharaoh said that it was only magic and summoned all the magicians in the land to come and defeat the 'magic' of Moses (which wasn't magic because it was a miracle from God)

The Pharaoh said to the magicians that if they defeat Moses' 'magic' with their magic they will be of those who are 'brought close to' Pharaoh.

I want a single word to describe 'those brought close' to the Pharaoh

'Confidants' isn't right in this context because the magicians are not promised that they will become advisers to Pharaoh.

Comment: The King has a *Court*, composed of his *courtiers*. Those who the King trusts and relies on for advice are his *advisers*.

Comment: Or _counsellors_

Comment: @DanBron Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @bib I'm starting my day now, but if someone wants to post *courtier* as an answer with more detail and references, he has my blessing.

Comment: There's also _entourage_.

Answer (score 1):

The particular relationship in the context you describe would seem to call for "favorite," as in this passage from a history blog:

For the first time in English history a monarch had to rule by the power of personal charisma alone. Elizabeth was not a King by right of battle like her grandfather Henry VII, nor was she the chosen leader of a powerful faction. She inherited by default, and she had to keep her position by power of personality alone. But this was almost impossible for a woman. All of the previous courtly rituals and circles of power and influence had depended on a male King with male favourites, who formed the intimate circle around him as courtiers and councilors,

Read more at: http://www.philippagregory.com/news/news/50
Source: Philippa Gregory

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need such a word? But in any case, 'advisors' is often used. 'Courtier' is also used.

Courtier:
1 : a gentleman attendant or habitu* of a sovereign's court;  sometimes   : a ruler's satellite especially given to flattery, soliciting favor, and connivance